# sed in bash script: unknown command: `''`

Tags: shell-script, sed

Is there a way in which I can use a `sed` command which includes apostrophe `'` in bash script or do I need to alter the `sed` command so that it doesn't use `'` ?

For example, I want to run this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file.txt | sed $'s|^\(some-string\)|\f\\1|'
```

The `sed` command is supposed to add a newline before every occurence of `some-string` inside . This doesn't work as the script only seems to run the cat command.

I also tried adding quotes `"` around the `sed` command:

```
cat file.txt | sed "$'s|^\(some-string\)|\f\\1|'"
```

It returns error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `''`
```

Running on Ubuntu 16.04 standard shell with `sh script.sh`.

Comment: This is working fine on `bash`, may be your script is running with the POSIX shell `sh`?

Comment: Ok, find the path of the `bash` from the terminal with `which bash` and set that to the interpreter after `#!` and give the script execute permissions and run it as `./<script>` so that the actual interpreter takes effect

Comment: @Inian it works now with making it executable `chmod +x script.sh` and then running `./script.sh`. Many thanks! You can add this as an answer. Will add distro info in question.

Comment: In your script, you can also get rid of `cat` and use the filename as the argument to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$'...'` like in C strings, `\f` is form-feed (FF, ^L). Newline is `\n` line-feed (LF, ^J). In standard `sed`, in the replacement part of the `s` command, it has to be inserted with `\` followed by a LF character:

So you want:

```
#! /bin/sh -
< file.txt sed '
  s|^some-string|\
&|'
```

With `$'...'`:

```
#! /bin/bash -
< file.txt sed $'s|^some-string|\\\n&|'
```

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can also use `\n` to mean newline/LF in the replacement:

```
#! /bin/sh -
< file.txt gnu-sed 's|^some-string|\n&|'
```

In any case, there's no apostrophe passed to `sed` in any of those commands. `'...'` and `$'...'` are quoting operators of the shell, the first one (standard) used to pass what's inside verbatim to `sed`, the second one (ksh93 extension now supported by a few other shells including `bash`) used to expand sequences like `\f`, `\n` in them before passing to `sed`.

If you wanted to pass a literal `'` to `sed`, for instance to pass it the `y/'/"/` command to substitute `'`s with `"`, you would use a shell quoting operator that allows passing `'`, which includes all quoting operators *except* `'...'` itself:

```
sed $'y/\'/"/'  # $'...' quoting operator
sed "y/'/\"/"   # "..." quoting operator
sed y/\'/\"/    # \x quoting operator
```

Comment: I see using `#! /bin/sh -` with the first example makes it run fine with `sh` command. Furthermore, as @Inian pointed out, making it executable and running it with `./script.sh` makes it run as I initially wrote it. Thanks for the extensive answer, helped clean my `sed` command a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Posixly sed way to accomplish this is:

```
$ sed -e '/^some_string/!b'  - e 'H;s/.*//;x' filename
```